# Using Polymer without Roboto

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, polymer-2.x, html-imports

I have a Polymer 2 app with an explicit `--paper-font-common-base` specified before loading any of the components:

```
--paper-font-common-base: {
    font-family: 'Comic Sans'; 
    /* Not really, nobody's that evil, but problem is there for any font */
};
```

Then, at some point when loading Polymer components, for instance [`paper-dialog`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog-behavior/blob/768729d22677442a833a2403df08173aa2a339dd/paper-dialog-shared-styles.html#L14), will import `typography.html`

```
<link rel="import" href="../paper-styles/typography.html">
```

In turn `typography.html` [imports Roboto](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/739c14c9114dd3f80172e43d4ea2c5faf9bae132/typography.html#L12) and [overrides the mixin](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/739c14c9114dd3f80172e43d4ea2c5faf9bae132/typography.html#L27-L30):

```
<link rel="import" href="../font-roboto/roboto.html">
...
<custom-style>
    <style is="custom-style">
        html {
            --paper-font-common-base: {
                font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            };
```

This overrides the font face I've specified, but also goes and downloads Roboto from [Google's CDN](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,700|Roboto:400,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic), which I explicitly do not want it to.

Other Polymer components, for instance [`paper-radio-button`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-radio-button/blob/2642fc7ee6e9a9371aa04a81c87dddd77a406944/paper-radio-button.html#L50-L51) take a different approach:

```
/*
This element applies the mixin `--paper-font-common-base` but does not import `paper-styles/typography.html`.
In order to apply the `Roboto` font to this element, make sure you've imported `paper-styles/typography.html`.
*/
```

How do I set `--paper-font-common-base` so that Polymer components use the same font as the rest of my application?

Comment: I am not sure, but isn't `html, paper-dialog { --paper-...}` enough? Just adding paper-dialog after html will apply css to paper dialog directly. Another option would be to import `typography.html` on your own before you define  ` --paper-font-common-base` in your style

Comment: @KubaŠimonovský it imports `typography.html` regardless, and importing it myself first still adds requests that I don't need to my page load before overriding them. Specifying the specific control doesn't stop that, even if I have a conclusive list of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like `<custom-style>` is loading directly into your `<head>` tags as it's wrapped in `<script>` tags.

To over ride this behaviour you'd need to add your script higher up in the `<head>` tags also.

Comment: Where are you getting that from? The `<custom-style>` cited in the question is imported in `typography.html` (part of [`paper-styles`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles), not my code) - my definition for `--paper-font-common-base` has already loaded before that import is requested.

Comment: Not sure - I just saw the <script> tags and just thought it must be in the <head> tags.  The other obvious thing to try would be !important, but I'd presume you wouldn't want to try this or as a long shot use @font-face and give it the name of Roboto as a workaround???

Comment: Where did you see `<script>` tags? `!important` flags on CSS rules is a bad cludge at the best of times, but it doesn't help at all with Shadow DOM at all as styles don't cascade.

Comment: `<style is="custom-style">`

Comment: I might have it wrong though, as my answer was pretty presumptive as I can't see the site, and inspect the element

Comment: That's a `<style>` tag, the `is=` is a Polymer web-components thing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this is to make your own `font-roboto` dependency with an empty `roboto.html` file. Then in your bower.json you would force your dependency to be the resolution to the `font-roboto` conflict.

Comment: That would stop the font being overridden, but would also cause additional requests and errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to

1. Fork `<paper-dialog>`, and remove the import of `typography.html`
2. Load your own copy of `<paper-dialog>`
3. File a ticket, or a pull request, for `<paper-dialog>`
4. If your change is officially accepted, load the official `<paper-dialog>`, again.

Comment: Cheers. I can do that as a last resort, but there are a _lot_ of Polymer components that do this, about half the `paper-*` ones, not just `paper-dialog`. I want to be sure there isn't a better way of doing this first.

Comment: I have raised [this issue with `paper-dialog`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog-behavior/issues/116) and [`paper-input`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/issues/584), but there are lots more places that do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this font to work on the entire web app, is your

```
--paper-font-common-base: {
    font-family: 'Comic Sans';
};
```

declared into a `custom-style` element ?

If not try that :

```
<custom-style>
  <style>
        html {
            --paper-font-common-base: {
                font-family: 'Comic Sans'; 
            };
        }
  </style>
</custom-style>
```

And if you add that into you root element, it should be applied in all the child elements except if some custom components override their own font.

## Edit :

There is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1iMlz6oovpcMcwaHCJuJ?p=preview) example.

Comment: Yes, that `<custom-style>` wrapper is exactly what I'm doing (mixins don't work at all without it) and custom components overriding their own font is exactly the problem I'm describing in the question. How do I stop Polymer custom elements (those coming specifically from the Polymer OSS teams) from overriding the mixin `--paper-font-common-base` that Polymer provides for global styling?

Comment: I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1iMlz6oovpcMcwaHCJuJ?p=preview)  that maybe can help you. For the typo to be set, I had to import the `typography.html` to `my-custom-style.html` element. Same for the color variable, without the `default-theme.html` import it didn't worked.

Comment: That appears to work and is a clever workaround, but still downloads typography and roboto, then overloads them. Ideally, I'd like to not download any resources my app doesn't need.

Answer (score 0):

In `.bowerrc` add this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node -e \"require('fs').writeFileSync('bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html', '')\""
  }
}
```

It will make `roboto.html` as an empty file without any error requests after build.

Comment: That's still a round trip for an empty file that shouldn't be requested in the first place. If I was going to post-process the library I'd removed references to the file, rather than emptying the file.

Comment: @Keith well, thats the quickest workaround on this issue unless you want to go through all `paper` elements. In that case your post-process script will be bigger. No additional requests will be made since `polymer build` will merge empty file to the main bundle. So emptying the file is better, unless you are using push protocol and building for it.